# Jquery draggable - Is possible to drag past margins?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div (child) within a div (parent). I centered the child div with `margin: auto;`. I made the child div draggable with `containment: "parent"` using JQuery's draggable function. However, since I set the margins to auto it will not let me drag the child div left or right. Is there anyway to allow draggable to avoid margins?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height : 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.child {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    height : 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: auto;
}
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(".child")
    .draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "move"
});
```

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLdrxybm/).

I have tried to set the margin to 0 when dragging starts but it looks pretty ugly. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xod8jfea/) for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve on Abdul's answer, when you add a margin to the child box, it literally has invisible sides on it that fill up the space between the left and right sides of the child and the left and right sides of the parent. So technically you are moving it around, it's just that there is no space for it to move left and right.

To fix this, remove the margin on the child and center it horizontally using the same technique you used to center it vertically:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad My answer clearly explains the problem that was encountered, as well as the solution, instead of just linking to a broken jsfiddle. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question to get it to work like you want. But I don't know if what you're doing is good or bad. here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hLdrxybm/2/

just remove the `margin` from child and you can add a `left` property so that the block looks centered. There are other ways to center a div, but I'm not sure that will do any good since you want draggable elements

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, this allows me to drag the child past the parent and doesn't allow me to drag to the bottom. The div also jumps when I start to drag which I do not want.

Comment: @Anthony how are you dragging past the parent? I'm trying it now and I can't drag past the parent. And what do you mean doesn't allow you to drag to the bottom? I can drag to the bottom just fine.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad if you click the green box and drag to the top, it goes outside of the orange box. This could be a browser issue for you.